# Alignat issue - extra space in one line

Tags: equations, align

My code looks like this:

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
\theta^2&\equiv\frac{2m a^2\epsilon}{\hbar^2},\ \lambda&\equiv&\theta^{\frac{2p}{p+1}}\frac{E}{\epsilon},\\
E&=\lambda\epsilon\theta^{-\frac{2p}{p+1}},\ u&=&\theta^{\frac{1}{p+1}}\frac{x}{a}
\end{alignat}
```

And the picture looks like this:
[image: picture]

Why is there extra space after lambda, and not after u? The first pair of equations in upper and lower row look good, why is second ones making an issue?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should position the ampersands slightly different.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % loads »amsmath«

\begin{document}
  \begin{alignat}{2}
    \theta^2 &\equiv \frac{2m a^2\epsilon}{\hbar^2}, & \lambda &\equiv \theta^{\frac{2p}{p+1}}\frac{E}{\epsilon},\\
    E &= \lambda\epsilon\theta^{-\frac{2p}{p+1}},\quad & u &= \theta^{\frac{1}{p+1}}\frac{x}{a} 
  \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seem to worked. I need to add blank space every time I want this effect in alignat?

Comment: No. It's just a common practise for me to keep track of the alignments.